# Issue while calling a Web Service through JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to call an external Web service via JQuery Ajax in the following format

```
$.ajax({
          url: "<web-service URL>",
          cache: false,
          success: function(html){
          alert( "Called");
                  }
            });
```

But it throws a `404 error` saying page not found.

I modified the Ajax call by replacing the URL with the following

```
$.ajax({
          url: "http://www.google.com",
          cache: false,
          success: function(html){
          alert( "Called");
                  }
            });
```

But i still got the `404 Error`, with the URL String looking something like this

```
http://localhost:8081/Application/root/www.google.com?_=1329471109853"
```

Unable to understand as to why is it appending the `google.com` URL to the `localhost`

Can anybody tell me what am i doing wrong , all i want to do is to call an external webservice URL in the background.

Comment: I don't see how is that related to Java or Spring-MVC, retagging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read about the [same-origin-policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).  You can only make ajax calls to the same host that the page you are on came from.  There are a few ways to work around this (like using JSONP), but you will have to code for and accept the limitations of those work-arounds.

Comment: And why this is the URL he is getting?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to perform a forbidden action: if such a call was legal, it would open a security hole, allowing malicious code to access undesired URLs silently...